# Conjecture: Given any $2n+1$ points, we can always draw $n$ non-intersecting circles whose diameter endpoints are $2n$ of those points.

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, circles, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

Is the following conjecture true or false:

> Given any $2n+1$ coplanar points, we can always draw $n$ non-intersecting circles coplanar with the points, whose diameter endpoints are $2n$ of those points.
> We consider tangent circles to be non-intersecting.

This is a generalization of my earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4809289/398708) about the case $n=2$. That question is currently unanswered. I wonder if it is [easier](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/2157/20101) to prove the general case.

Example:

[image: Example 1]

Another example:

[image: Example 2]

I cannot find a counter-example, nor can I prove the conjecture.

I made a [generator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uuj7shw4is?lang=zh-CN) of seven (pseudo)random points.

(If, instead, we were given $2n$ points, the conjecture would not be true: for example, if the $2n$ points were the vertices of a regular $(2n-1)$-gon plus the centre, then we could not draw $n$ non-intersecting circles.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not true for $n=3$. Consider 7 points on the complex plane in such location: one at $0$ and other 6 at $0.01\omega^i,\omega^i, i=0,1,2$, where $\omega$ is the 3-th unit root ($-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$).

Comment: Three circles with diameters from $0.01\omega^i$ to $\omega^i$ does it.

Comment: No they intersect with each other